# Filter by user specific data but also using a searchengine like Solr

Tags: database, solr, nosql, relational-database

I'm using a relational DB for items, and index them with Solr for getting the fast full-text search that Solr provides. But in the same time, I need the user to be able to filter by item status, that is of course a value particular to this user.

An ItemUserStatus value is  an association between: an item, a user and a status, so it's a different table.
So I need to use the searching capabilities of Solr, but need in the same query to filter by user specific information that does not seem indexable to me.

An example query would sound like: get me the items with title "Title" that you have set in the "Pending" state.
I'm not sure what is the best way to do this, or if I'm using the right tools.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

When designing your Solr schema, you need to [denormalize/flatten your data](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign). In this case, it seems that you're searching for "items", so the schema would revolve around items. When populating your Solr index, you'd have a field "Title" and another dynamic field "State", so your query would be as simple as `Title:something State_123:Pending` where 123 is the user id.

Comment: Hi, the State value is specific to a user and an item. So it's a value in a table with columns: id, user_id, item_id, state_id . So it is Pending for one user, but may be Closed for another one. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mauricio. So this means that for every item I will index all the states the users have saved for that item. So for example, if 10,000 users have an item in state Pending, I will have  10,000 different State_xxxx:Pending indexed for that item. And similar goes for every item. Is this efficient ?

Comment: @StefanH: yes it is. Solr is **not a relational database**, so you can't apply efficiency criteria for relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net). It is a document-oriented database built on top of Lucene, so you get a hybrid of Solr and a database, with the exception it is not meant to be a search engine, but rather a full featured doc-database with full-text search support on text fields.

A Linq expression to query RavenDB for your example would then be:

```
from doc in docs
where doc.Title == "Title" && doc.State == DocState.Pending
select doc
```

Comment: I use Linux, I see RavenDB is Windows stuff